# self.splitViewController.navigationController pushViewController can't work

Tags: objective-c

`UIsplitViewController` can't pushViewController, only the `master view` or only `detail view` can pushViewController inside it's view. I wan't to push a new view int the current `UIsplitViewController`. The `UIsplitViewController` is in a `UITabBarController`.

How to solve it?

Comment: To navigate between viewcontrollers it requires NavigationController. You can set your splitviewcontroller as rootviewcontroller to Navigationcontroller and set that navigation controller in Tabbarcontroller. Also manage navigationbar show/hide if you don't require.

Comment: @Samir I can't set splitviewcontroller to Navigationcontroller.  How to make it?

Comment: If you are using Storyboard Take Navigation controller. Remove its default viewcontroller. And set Splitviewcontroller as NavigationContr's rootviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

```
        self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden;
        [MLTool pushView:self newView:USER_VIEW];

    +(id)pushView:(UIViewController*)view newView:(NSString*)newView{
        UIViewController *svc = [view.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:newView];
        //NSAssert(svc, @"pushView nil");
        [view.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
        return svc;
    }

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    SplitProductView* split=(SplitProductView* )self.splitViewController;
    [split resetSplit:   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];

    //self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay
}

-(void)resetSplit :(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        //TODOX:iphone
        if (isPad)
        {
            if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)){
                self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay;
            }
            else{
                //if (self.displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay)
                {//ios的bug,必须这三行,不然左边有黑边

                    //  if (SYSTEM_VERSION_MORE_THAN(@"8.0"))
                    {
                        self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden;
                        self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;
                        self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAutomatic;
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```